# What capacitor to use for high voltage & high current filter application

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, high-current, passive-filter

I am designing a filter that needs a capacitor. I am not allowed to paste the schematic here, so only the maximum voltage at and current through the cap, pasted from the spice simulation:

[image: current through and voltage at the capacitor]

(voltage is purple, current is blue)

It should have 2,2uF capacity.

It cannot be e-cap because the voltage can go negative (again down to ca -300V, with similar current shapes).

The question is what other type of capacitor to use?

I've considered this type:

https://www.tme.eu/en/details/wxpc-225k/x2-y2-foil-polypropylene-capacitors/miflex/

https://www.tme.eu/Document/b4386034adefaa335c5813b75e3b0989/wxpc300_ang.pdf

Does this cap withstand the currents? What about the leads? Do they withstand the currents?

The datasheet says nothing about current limits the capacitor can withstand for such or similar repetitive currents (its internal construction, leads etc.). I know about ESR and its influence on temperature rise but the datasheet only mentions dissipation factor @1kHz. Does this parameter help here or how do I calculate the ESR from this and the temperature rise in my case?

I know I can physically test the cap and measure its temperature rise but I would like to calculate it first theoretically to see if the cap is really safe to use.

Comment: Do you need the safety rating? Because I see ceramic capacitors on Digikey that might fit (and have ripple current ratings). You might also find you need to parallel several smaller-value capacitors.

Comment: What is your source impedance that is driving the cap?

Comment: capacitors typically have a max ripple current spec

Comment: X and Y capacitors are intended to be used for AC line filtering. If a high current rating would be needed for such an application, one really should reconsider the design! Thats the reason those caps don't have a RMS rating. Next, they're intended for 50/60 Hz, not 50kHz. Hence the dissipation factor at 1kHz instead of the typical 100kHz.

Comment: Ok, I've found detailed calculation here https://cz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/212/kemet_01152019_KEM_F3116_C4AF-1522592.pdf. I'll use this. For my calculation, I'll approximate I(50kHz) to ca 4A (RMS) and neglect the higher harmonics. Seems to be sufficient to me. And if thermal derating is required, I'll use two caps in parallel.